# Disabling a web service after deploying it in JBoss

Tags: java, web-services, ear, jboss6.x, struts1

I have two wars, sar and ejb packaged in an ear. One of war has rest web service in it. I'm deploying this ear in JBoss 6 AS. Is there way with which I can disable the web service deployed in it.

Comment: why not remove said web service?

Comment: I need way to switch on and off the web service

Comment: Maybe you could make use of JMX

Comment: Can u guide me to any example

Comment: Just found [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/1352/what-is-jmx-mbean-jconsole-tutorial) on *google*.